# Handling app crashes for Parent-Child managedObjectContexts

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift2

Here is a sample application application I created to mimic the case I'm working on. It is a single view application that uses CoreData and Swift 2.0 with Xcode 7 beta4

So in my View Controller I create a `privateObjectContext` that is a child of the `mainManagedObjectContext`

```
let mainMOC = AppDelegate().managedObjectContext
var privateObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    privateObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
    privateObjectContext?.parentContext = mainMOC
}
```

I know that saving in the child MOC syncs it to the parent and then saving the parent will save it to the persistent store but saving the main MOC everytime I save my child MOC doesn't make sense and makes the purpose of child MOC redundant. SO after all my testing is done I save my parent MOC and it does get stored in the persistent Store as expected.

But when I simulate a crash on the application ( by going to the task manager and forcibly killing the application) it doesn't get stored in the persistent manager; which it should have because of this

```
func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
        // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
        self.saveContext()
    }

func saveContext () {
        if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                abort()
            }
        }
    }
```

But `managedObjectContext.hasChanges` returns false, despite it having changes in the ViewController
Am I wrong somewhere in the lifecycle of the the MOC?

--EDIT
I use an extension to NSManagedObjectContext to create test objects in bulk

```
privateObjectContext?.performBlock {
            self.privateObjectContext?.createTestObjects(100) {
                (person: Person, index) in
                person.name = "Test Person \(index)"
            }
            do {
                try self.privateObjectContext?.save()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

        }
```

After this if I fetch from my main MOC then i get as expected 100 records.

```
print(mainMOC.hasChanges) //true
let persons = mainMOC.fetchAll(Person)
print(persons.count) //100
```

But after forcibly crashing the app the main MOC still shows no changes.

Comment: What is the motivation to use child context in your case? Do you see any concurrent usage?

Comment: I have a lot of data that needs to be saved in the background at regular intervals of time in my main application. So was looking at the option of saving it to the MOC asynchronously through a child MOC and then when the user is done with the task to store it in the persistent store. I had to handle the case when the app crashes in between the task too, hence the question

Comment: Ideally, a save on parent should immediately follow the save on the child context if you intend to write the updates back to disk immediately.

Comment: I actually don't want to write the changes to disk immediately and occupy my main queue, but only if the app crashes or something

Answer (score 2):

The application will terminate method is basically never used, so you shouldn't rely on it. You also shouldn't really be coding to save on crash, firstly your app shouldn't crash and secondly it's hard to know what data is invalid on crash so you may be corrupting otherwise good data.

In general you should either save immediately or batch save up to the persistent store.

Note that you can also construct your managed object contexts differently so things are processed and saved and then merged down to the main context. You probably only want to go to this effort if you're actually seeing problems at the UI when saving.

---

Strictly for your issue, the problem is that you aren't saving the child MOC (at least not in the code we can see). So, when you come to save the main MOC it doesn't have any of the child changes yet and there is nothing to be saved.

Comment: The case I was considering was the worst case scenario where the app for some reason crashes. I definitely do save data to the persistent coordinator from time to time.
But the `applicationWillTerminate` method is called when i kill it but the MOC shows no changes. Why is that?

Comment: Hi..I've edited my code to show the test case where I do save my child MOC and it does get reflected in the main MOC as it should but doesnt show changes in the ApllicationWillTerminate method. NSManagedObjectContext is a class so should be references correctly or maybe I am missing something here witht he lifecycle of it

Answer (score 1):

If you have lot of saves to be made, and as @Wain rightly pointed out that, it is not a good idea to perform saves on termination, there is a more recommended way to do this without choking the main thread. You will need to create a root context, that is associated with the store coordinator and runs in a non main queue. Your main context can be the child of this context.

Refer section ' Asynchronous Saving' in

https://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/

Comment: i could look into this. Thanks!! Though i still don't get why the main MOC shows no changes even after saving my child MOC

Comment: OK, would there be any possibility to take look at your actual code?